# How to add VSTO Outlook addin in start up?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a ribbon xml which adds a button and have certain functionality. But what C# lines I have to write in Thisaddin_startup() to make the button available in Outlook while starting up? If  I run the project I am not able to see any buttons in Outlook Addin.

```
 public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    EpicTest obj = new EpicTest();
    Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;
    Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();

    private Outlook.Explorer explorer = null;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        return new EpicTest();
    }
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }
    void timerDelay_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am adding some button in mail Tab in outlook addin. You need to put following code in EpicTest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" 
onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
```

```
           label="Custom Addin">
      <button id="xxuususuxx" label="Setting" onAction="Setting_OnAction" size="large" imageMso="TableSharePointListsModifyColumnsAndSettings"/>

    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
```

Add following code in ThisAddIn

```
  protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility 
   CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
   {
  return new EpicTest(); //ribbonitem is name of instance of ribbonclass 
  }
```

in EpicTest.cs file

```
public void Setting_OnAction(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        //your custom code for when button is click such as messagebox etc
    }//
```

You do not need to create instance of Application. You can access it this.Application .